# Xcode 5: storyboard window is a separate window

Tags: xcode5

I accidentally double clicked on the storyboard window and now it is a separate window.  This is not what I wanted.  How do I make the storyboard window a part of the Xcode primary editor?

Answer (score 3):

Use **Assistant Editor** mode to glue storyboard into Xcode.

[image]

So the editor now look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just close the undesired window and reselect the storyboard by clicking on it in the Project Navigator in your main Xcode window. It should then open the storyboard in the main Xcode window as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if I understand you correctly, you just need to close the Storyboard window. Once you do this, you can click on the storyboard on the left hand file navigator and it'll appear again as normal.

I actually use this when I have a lot of Views on the go with an extended desktop. It allows me to see the different views on a larger screen, while keeping the code in front of me.